# How to use an activity component in different fragments with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity with 5 fragments. i'm using different functionalities on the same component's onClick inside different fragments. because of viewpager's fragment preloading, functionality of next fragment is executed instead of current fragment. what should i do?

Comment: please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to avoid it because of view pager has minimim offset is 1.

So I would suggest to you using another way to archive your result:

**Idea 1**: If you are using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` second parameter as `FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`, it means only one fragment inside your view pager will be in `onResume` state. Therefore you could start all of your networking/side effects job in `onResume` method.

**Idea 2**: Why do you using view pager, when you do not need swipe left/right effect? Probably you are in the wrong way. You could use for example just frame layout, then with your fragment manager attach and detach fragment when a user interacts how you expected. I would advise you to look better at `FragmentTransaction`. [Here is a link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction).

Feel free to ask me about one of these approaches.

Comment: I use a step indicator library that needs viewpager to work. moving some parts into onResume method worked. thanks.